# Passing the isLoading value to my component in nuxtjs app

Tags: vuejs2, nuxt.js

Can anyone help with this, I'm trying to not render the component until the data has loaded

In my page I have

```
async asyncData ({ params, store, isLoading=true}) {
    const thisCaseId = store.dispatch('cases/getCase', params.caseId ); 
      isLoading = false
    return { thisCaseId, isLoading}
  },
```

Console logging confirms my isLoading does change from True to false

I thought I could pass this down to the component through a prop as follows

```
<case-summary  :isLoading='isLoading' :caseId='caseId'></case-summary>
```

and then use a v-if on the container

```
<section class="case-summary-container" v-if="!isLoading">
```

But that doesn't work, although the isLoading value does appear to be passing to the child component through a prop as expected and working, just doesn't wait to render.

I also tried using the same on the page element before rendering the component

```
 <b-card v-if="isLoading">
            <h2>Loading ...</h2>
        </b-card>

        <b-card v-if="!isLoading">
          <case-summary  :caseId='caseId'></case-summary>
        </b-card>
```

but this didn't work either.

Can anyone explain this to me please and what I would need to do to make this work as I still in both cases get that flicker where the previous record is displayed before re rendering the new results (Which is what I am trying to stop)

I should add I am passing an object so can't use .length although I assume as the previous content is still there this wouldn't work anyway

basically I want to delay loading my component until the new data has populated it

my action in my store is as follows

```
getCase ({ commit, context }, data) {
    return new Promise ((reject) => {
      this.$axios.get('/cases/' + data + '.json')
    .then(res => {
      const obj = {};
        Object.assign(obj, res.data);
        commit('GET_CASE', obj)
      })
      .catch(e => {
        context.error(e)
        reject('/cases/')
        this.loading = false
      })
    })
  },
```

Many Thanks

Comment: asyncData is serverside, if you set isLoading false before its rendered then whats the point in using it.. also use `return { thisCaseId: thisCaseId, isLoading: isLoading}`

Comment: @LawrenceCherone asyncData both serverside and clientside.

Comment: It doesnt wait for render because u dont do  await store.dispatch.

Comment: Many thanks, I did try const thisCaseId = await store.dispatch('cases/getCase', params.caseId ); but then nothing happened at all

Comment: Because you need promise and resolve in your vuex action

Comment: Thankyou @Aldarund, now working as I wanted, thank you so much

Comment: @Paul fyi, you should accept answers that solve your questions for your previous and future questions :)

Comment: @Aldarund Apologies, just spotted the tick, will do so from now on, thanks